# why am i getting error in manpy package installation

Tags: python, anaconda

I tried to install the `manpy` package which is a part of `dream` project from their github repository (https://github.com/nexedi/dream) with anaconda prompt. But after the installation is finished and I try to open it in Jupiter notebook by running the code: `from dream.Simulation.Queue import Queue` I am getting the error of `no module named CoreObject`. 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btohF.jpg)

Comment: Please also include the full error traceback in a code-block. That makes it easier for us to help.

Comment: I have attached the full error traceback image.